# Extract substring from URL / value of a key from URL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, substring, extract

I have a table which has "url" column.

I need to extract all the values of "tag".

**TableA**

```
#+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|   url                                                               |
#+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|   https://www.amazon.in/primeday?tag=final&value=true               | 
#|   https://www.filipkart.in/status?tag=presubmitted&Id=124&key=2     | 
#|   https://www.google.com/active/search?tag=inreview&type=addtional  |
#|   https://www.google.com/filter/search?&type=nonactive              |
```

**Output**

```
#+------------------+
#|   Tag            |
#+------------------+
#|   final          | 
#|   presubmitted   | 
#|   inreview       |
```

I am able to do it in Spark SQL using this:

```
spark.sql("""select parse_url(url,'QUERY','tag') as Tag from TableA""")
```

Any option via dataframe or regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PySpark:

```
df \
  .withColumn("partialURL", split("url", "tag=")[1]) \
  .withColumn("tag", split("partialURL", "&")[0]) \
  .drop("partialURL")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below implementation -

```
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
      import spark.implicits._
      val extract: String => String = StringUtils.substringBetween(_,"tag=","&")
      val parse = udf(extract)
      val urlDS = Seq("https://www.amazon.in/primeday?tag=final&value=true",
                      "https://www.filipkart.in/status?tag=presubmitted&Id=124&key=2",
                      "https://www.google.com/active/search?tag=inreview&type=addtional",
                      "https://www.google.com/filter/search?&type=nonactive").toDS
    
      urlDS.withColumn("tag",parse($"value")).show()


+----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|value                                                           |tag         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|https://www.amazon.in/primeday?tag=final&value=true             |final       |
|https://www.filipkart.in/status?tag=presubmitted&Id=124&key=2   |presubmitted|
|https://www.google.com/active/search?tag=inreview&type=addtional|inreview    |
|https://www.google.com/filter/search?&type=nonactive            |null        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: I don't recommend using a UDF unless absolutely necessary. They are generally harder to debug and slower than using built-in Spark SQL functions. The `substringBetween` used inside this answer's UDF is the same functionality as Pardeep's answer, yet that one is going to be faster and easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution is likely `substring` based, similar to Pardeep's answer. An alternative approach is to use a regex that does some light input checking, similar to:

```
^(?:(?:(?:https?|ftp):)?\/\/).+?tag=(.*?)(?:&.*?$|$)
```

This checks that the string starts with a `http`/`https`/`ftp` protocol, the colon and slashes, at least one character (lazily), and either `tag=<string of interest>` appears somewhere in the middle or at the very end of the string.

Visually (courtesy of regex101), the matches look like:
[image: An image showing different test strings, where only proper URLs containing tag= match.]

The `tag` values you want are in capture group 1, so if you use `regexp_extract` ([PySpark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html)), you'll want to use `idx` of `1` to extract them.

The main difference between this answer and Pardeep's is that this one won't extract values from strings that don't conform to the regex, e.g. the last string in the image above doesn't match. In these edge cases, `regexp_extract` will return a `NULL`, which you can process as you wish afterwards.

Since we're invoking a regex engine, this approach is likely a little slower, but the performance difference might be imperceptible in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Since **Spark 3.5+** [`parse_url`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.parse_url.html#pyspark.sql.functions.parse_url) is available in Python API.

```py
F.parse_url('url', F.lit('QUERY'), F.lit('tag'))
```

Since **Spark 2.0+** it was only available in Spark SQL which is accessed with `expr`:

```py
F.expr("parse_url(url, 'QUERY', 'tag')")
```

---

Dataframe examples:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('https://www.amazon.in/primeday?tag=final&value=true',),
     ('https://www.filipkart.in/status?tag=presubmitted&Id=124&key=2',),
     ('https://www.google.com/active/search?tag=inreview&type=addtional',),
     ('https://www.google.com/filter/search?&type=nonactive',)],
    ['url'])

df.select(
    F.parse_url('url', F.lit('QUERY'), F.lit('tag')).alias('tag_1'),
    F.expr("parse_url(url, 'QUERY', 'tag')").alias('tag_2'),
).show()
# +------------+------------+
# |       tag_1|       tag_2|
# +------------+------------+
# |       final|       final|
# |presubmitted|presubmitted|
# |    inreview|    inreview|
# |        NULL|        NULL|
# +------------+------------+
```